# Labelling Several Cards in Trello

Tags: trello

Is it possible to add label colours to several cards at once?
Perhaps some kind of select all option?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, it is not possible to select multiple cards and apply a label to them; you have to add the labels individually.

Using the <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>6</kbd> [keyboard shortcuts](https://trello.com/shortcuts) can make this easier, because you can add the label without having to open the card or the labels menu.

Comment: Blew. My. Mind. You can also hover and press `m` for adding members

Comment: Note that this answer is no longer completely accurate. While bulk update functionality doesn't exist in base application, there are power-ups that provide this.  I have been using [Bulk Actions](https://trello.com/power-ups/5e4464985fd190825d164de3/bulk-actions)

Comment: couple this with `Right Arrow` for stepping between issues.

Answer (score 3):

**[Selección múltiple para Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiselect-for-trello/jlnfnpelianecpjoeahaeihmkhnkakof)** is an **extension for Google Chrome** that can handle what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I have been doing this using the free Trello power-up [Bulk Actions](https://trello.com/power-ups/5e4464985fd190825d164de3/bulk-actions).  Works great.

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2021, the Bulk actions power-up works really well.